# Can't connect to Tekkit server, lagged out by floating blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am running a Tekkit 3.1 Server on a Linux Debian 64 bit virtual machine with 4GB ram allocated for it.  Today, I noticed a lot of lag, and then went to my quarry and noticed I didn't have my teleport pipe at the right frequency.  Before I could pick up the blocks I was lagged out, and now I can't connect. When I try my client give me a grey screen.  I stopped the server immediately to prevent more block from piling up, but I still can't connect.

How can I save my map? Is there a way to remove all broken floating blocks?

Comment: stop the quarry and wait 5 minutes, or wait until the quarry it done and wait another 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try stopping the quarry; if you can do it, it'll be much easier to fix it, since the items will despawn automatically. Otherwise, you can try to use MCEdit and remove the item entities that are causing the lag.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to stop the quarry.  I logged into Tekkit, loaded up a single player map, then logged into the server and punched away the power teleport pipe (I lagged out right next to the quarry so I was close). My hypothesis was that if I load up a single player map, I have memory allocated, textures loaded, etc. before I jump into the server. I don't know if that helped, but then in the end something worked.

Answer (score -4):

first of all, back up the server. second of all, try deleting one of the worlds to see if that helps and then the server will regenerate them. Try taking it off the virtual machine just until it gets fixed. You made the back up if this doesn't work.

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the problem?